# Change Views filter depending on role

Tags: 7, views

I have a view where you can search for a number of users. Each of the 5 roles are limited to search for different roles of users, in a slightly complex matrix form.

A user can have multiple roles assigned to them too.

How do I restrict the "Filter: User Role" field depending on the role of the user using the search? I was initially planning to use contextual filters, but it appears to be more complex than that.

Can I use a hook or theme template to filter the results of the view depending on the user role?